# How do I link to a php file in my plugin directory?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin

Basically in the `wp-admin` section I have a page where I attempt to export some records from a grid. I have an Export link which leads to something like `admin.php?page=download&selected_ids=1,2,4`. But when I click it I get the following error:

> You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.

I think I need to first somehow register this page into WordPress before I can reach it through the URL. The page is just a download script called `download.php` so I don't want it to appear anywhere. It's only there to allow me to export some things and it's located in `my-plugin-directory/lib/download.php`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `admin.php?action=my_action` and WordPress will fire the equivalent action hook:

```
// How to get the URL
$url = admin_url( "admin.php?action=wpse_21460_export&any_other_arguments" );

// How to handle the URL
function wpse_21460_export() {
   // Do your export and exit
}

add_action( 'admin_action_wpse_21460_export', 'wpse_21460_export' );
```

See how WordPress formats the hook name to `admin_action_{value_of_action_param}`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will need to add it via `add_menu_page` - but in the callback function you register that displays the page, you could re-direct away from it (or just display your own message), as needed.

You could also remove it from showing up on the admin menu by calling `remove_menu_page` right after you add it.  That ought to leave the page registered (with the access permissions needed, etc.) but simply keep it from appearing on the menu.